# OpenLayers 3 Examples - EPSG:4326 example does not operate

Tags: openlayers-3

I am trying to use OpenLayers 3 Examples. But recently EPSG:4326 example does not operate. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The url inside layers(TileWms) doesn't work anymore.So try with another Url

or get the service(url) from geoserver.